# MongoDB Java driver returns exploded ObjectId

Tags: java, mongodb, objectid

I'm just doing some CRUD on a **Mongo** database with **Java**.

My problem is when I query the database, for example:

```
db.getCollection("something").find(query);
```

I get the documents correctly, however the **ObjectId** of each document is something like this:

```
"_id": {
  "timestamp": 1459641911,
  "machineIdentifier": 16375804,
  "processIdentifier": 3908,
  "counter": 9920756,
  "time": 1459641911000,
  "date": "2016-04-03T00:05:11.000+0000",
  "timeSecond": 1459641911
}, ...
```

But I need it to be the **12-byte representation**, like this:

```
ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011")
```

How can I do that? Preferably without any Java manipulation.

Thank you

Comment: what mongo driver are U using

Comment: @Koitoer I'm using mongodb-driver 3.2.2